# how to obtain the android signed map key during signing process?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to generate the signed map key for google maps. Currently i have generated a map key and using in the app. I came to know that we need to change the google map api key during the code signing process, i mean at the time of app distribution. How to get the **Signed** Google map api key ?

Also please tell me why to change the map api key ?

**Edit**
I have generated the keystore for signing the app.

 I am developing app in version Android 2.2.

 If i need to generate the new key, how to generate it ?

Comment: are u using android mapapi v1 or v2

Comment: if you are using v1 no need to change the key..it will work perfectly..

Comment: @Janmejoy, I am developing app on Vesion Android2.2. I need to generate new map api key?

Answer (score 2):

The map API key is generated depending on the certificate used to sign the application.

So if you change your signing certificate (for example when going from using the debug certificate to the release certificate), you must generate a new API key (at least for Maps API v1)

If you are using **API v1**, you should hurry as this won't be possible anymore starting **March 18th**.

If you are using **API v2**, you don't have to generate a new key. You can associate the signing certificate with an existing API key from the developer console.

Comment: thanks for reply, I developing app on Android2.2 version. Do i need to change the map api key ?

Answer (score 1):

First need to get the MD5 fingerprint of the debug certificate. When you are ready to release your application, register your release certificate with the Google Maps service for marketing purpose.

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey)

Check [this](http://seasonofrejoice.blogspot.in/) link for android map apiv2 integration.Hope it may help you!!

Comment: can i use the  Google Maps Android API v2 if my app is  in google apis Android2.2. I mean only for maps can i use Version2 or i need to update total project.

Comment: yes it will be fine..!!!but you can't run apiv2 in emulator it will work in device !!!

Comment: i have generated the map api key using same process. why i need to generate new key again. **why the old api key isn't useful**?

Comment: @muralidumpala in Api v2 the same key will not work you have use the SHA1 fingerprint with package name.,you can use the same fingerprint,,but not the same key right!!